# SSAS Link 2 Fact Tables together - how?

Tags: ssas, dimensions, ssas-2012

I have an SSAS which has a number of fact tables inside - each using "Regular" Dimensions (in the Dimension Usage Tab).  This works fine in isolation, now I need a little more breadth from the Cube.

I have a FactServiceRequest Table which has all of the SR details in, linked to a regular DimLocation.  Similarly I have a FactDog table which has a list of the Dog details in, again using the same DimLocation (i.e. addresses that the dogs are registered to).

So I have 2 measure groups columns and 1 (Dim) row, both using Location Alternate Key

I had expected that I would be able to select the Dog, the address that they are registered to and then the Incidents that were related to that address and dog.  However I am returning an almost exponential number of results - every incident for everything etc.

Can anyone help please?  I guess it will come down to the join of the facts to the dims but am unsure which direction to head in.

Answer (score 1):

It's a tricky question with a few possible answers.

It comes down to the fact (if you'll excuse this word-usage!) that Dog is both a dimension and a fact:

1. A Dog is a fact because it exists.  I'm guessing your measure in MeasureGroup Dog is a simple Count (slice by Location to get "how many dogs in this location"?)
2. A Dog is also a dimension, which slices the ServiceRequest facts.

One possible approach is to collapse (denormalise) the Service Requests in the database which acts as the cube source, so that every SR row includes all the Dog details.  This implies that there'll be a lot of a repetition, which has two disadvantages:

- It takes up more space, and introduces the risk of not correctly updating ALL copies of Dog details consistently (your ETL will have be extra-carefully built).
- Any other measures that really relate to the Dog, not the SR (such as, for example, the dog's age), will become hard to aggregate.

But in this approach, you only have one measure group.

The different approach I've taken in a few projects is to leave the fact tables as they are (1 for Dog, 1 for SR).  But then you can create *both* a Dimension *and* a measure-group off the Dog table.  In the cube Dimension Usage, you can relate "MeasureGroup Dogs" to "Dimension Dogs" through a "Fact"-type relationship (the short description in the dialog helpfully says "The dimension table is the fact table").

The Dog dimension can then relate to dimensions that are based on the ServiceRequest table (e.g. Type of ServiceRequest, Date of ServiceRequest) through the "many-to-many"-type relationship, passing through the ServiceRequest fact table/measuregroup.

Comment: Thankyou @SebTHU, Option 2 seems like the way to go for me.  Thank you for your time.

Comment: @user3735855: Glad I could help!  If my answer has solved the problem, please mark it as "accepted answer" (how this site works).